# Find the real part of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I am interested in finding the real part of this

$$\frac{z+2i}{z-2i} + 2i$$

Comment: Drop the irrelevant $2i$ and multiply top and bottom by $z^\ast+2i$, then take the real part.

Comment: how to drop 2i? divide everything by 2i? or ? Nevermind got it

Comment: Is $z$ a complex number?

Comment: No, @J.G.means that you only need to consider the fraction. Since $2i$ is purely imaginary anyway, it does not contribute to the real part

Comment: yes. thanks guys, i've got it in the end... I did nto think of it that way i was just trying to multiply by conjugate but did not managed to get anything now it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To express $\frac 1z$ in $a + b i$ format multiply the numerator and denominater by $\overline z$.  $z\overline z$ is always a real number so $\frac 1z = \frac 1z \frac {\overline z}{\overline z} = \frac {\overline z}{z\overline z}$ will be easy to put into $a + bi$ form.

Example:

$\frac 1{a+bi} = \frac 1{a+bi}\frac {a-bi}{a-bi}=\frac {a -bi}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac a{a^2 + b^2} - \frac b{a^2 + b^2} i$.

....

So in this one if we assume $z = a + bi$ then

$\frac {z + 2i}{z - 2i} +2i= \frac {a + (b+2)i}{a + (b-2)i}=$

$\frac {(a+(b+2)i)(a - (b-2)i)}{(a + (b-2)i)(a-(b-2)i)} + 2i=$

......